# How to set the path for a pdfsharp image

Tags: pdfsharp

I am trying to insert images into my Pdf. I am retrieving the image from my db with the url. It is not using the right path to the document. the exception shows that it is looking for the image at

> C:\MeasurementPictures\Kelly-Word-Front-3-24-2015-4-37-AM.jpg

the actual physical path to the images is

> C:\Development\FitFactor\FitFactor\MeasurementPictures\Kelly-Word-Front-3-24-2015-4-37-AM.jpg

[image]

```
XImage image = XImage.FromFile(model.FrontPicture.PictureUrl);
            gfx.DrawImage(image, 20, 100, 250, 140);
```

Code to Save Picture URL

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MeasurementPictures/");
  string vPath = root.Replace(@"C:\Development\FitFactor\FitFactor", "~").Replace("\\", "/").Replace("~/", "/");

  string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}{3}", clientName, model.PictureType, dt, clientExtension);
  string combination = Path.Combine(vPath, fileName);

   model.PictureUrl = combination;

  string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/MeasurementPictures");
  string relativePath = Path.Combine(physicalPath, fileName).Replace("\\", "/");
```

Would I use something like this?

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MeasurementPictures/");
            string vPath = root.Replace(@"C:\Development\FitFactor\FitFactor", "~").Replace("\\", "/").Replace("~/", "/");
            string relativePath = Path.Combine(vPath, model.FrontPicture.PictureUrl).Replace("\\", "/");

            XImage image = XImage.FromFile(relativePath);
            gfx.DrawImage(image, 20, 100, 250, 140);
```

Comment: You do not need MapPath if images have an absolute position. Use MapPath if images are stored relative to your project (but then you would not need Replace). Maybe something simple like `XImage.FromFile(Path.Combine(@"C:\Development\FitFactor\FitFactor\MeasurementPictures", model.FrontPicture.PictureUrl))` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string filePath = model.FrontPicture.PictureUrl.Replace("C:", " ");
 string completeFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath);
 XImage image = XImage.FromFile(Path.Combine(completeFilePath));
 gfx.DrawImage(image, 20, 100, 250, 140);
```

Here is the winning combination

Answer (score 0):

The .NET method `Path.Combine` can be used in cases like this.

Pass an absolute filename to PDFsharp and PDFsharp will use the correct file.

You could also set the working directory if you call `XImage.FromFile` with a relative path, but I'd use the former approach.

Comment: ok, i think i understand what you are saying. can u see updated post please

Comment: still getting the same error. i am using  XImage image = XImage.FromFile(Path.Combine(@"C:\Development\FitFactor\FitFactor\MeasurementPi‌​ctures", model.FrontPicture.PictureUrl));
                gfx.DrawImage(image, 20, 100, 250, 140);

Comment: ive been trying different combinations but it still keeps the C:\\ in there